# Error while indexing in Hibernate Search - Could not get property value

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search with Spring Boot to create a searchable rest api. Trying to POST an instance of "Training", I receive the following stack traces. None of the two are very insightful to me which is why I am reaching out for help.

Stack trace:
https://pastebin.com/pmurg1N3

It appears to me that it is trying to index a null entity!? How can that happen? Any ideas?

The entity:

```
@Entity @Getter @Setter @NoArgsConstructor
@ToString(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Audited @Indexed(index = "Training")
@AnalyzerDef(name = "ngram",
    tokenizer = @TokenizerDef(factory = StandardTokenizerFactory.class ),
    filters = {
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = StandardFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = LowerCaseFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = StopFilterFactory.class),
      @TokenFilterDef(factory = NGramFilterFactory.class,
        params = {
          @Parameter(name = "minGramSize", value = "2"),
        } 
      )
    }
)
@Analyzer(definition = "ngram")
public class Training implements BaseEntity<Long>, OwnedEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @ToString.Include
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @RestResourceMapper(context = RestResourceContext.IDENTITY, path = "/companies/{id}")
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    @JsonDeserialize(using = RestResourceURLSerializer.class)
    private Long owner;

    @NotNull
    @Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.YES, store = Store.YES)
    private String name;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String goals;

    @Column(length = 10000)
    private String description;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, bridge=@FieldBridge(impl=EnumBridge.class))
    private Audience audience;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, bridge=@FieldBridge(impl=EnumBridge.class))
    private Level level;

    @ManyToMany
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @NotNull @Size(min = 1)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Set<ProductVersion> versions;

    @NotNull
    private Boolean enabled = false;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO)
    @NumericField
    private Integer maxStudents;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Agenda agenda;

    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    @Field(index = Index.YES, store = Store.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO)
    @NumericField
    private Integer durationDays;

    @IndexedEmbedded
    @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say either your `versions` collection or your `tags` collection contains `null` objects, which is generally not something we expect in a Hibernate ORM association, and apparently not something Hibernate Search expects either.

Can you check that in debug mode?

Comment: That was the case, indeed, and should not happen in the first place. Which line from the stack trace was the indicator for you? This way I can find out myself next time.

Comment: Well I know the Hibernate Search codebase, so I cheated, but this one helped me: `Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not get property value` and just below: `at org.hibernate.search.util.impl.ReflectionHelper.getMemberValue(ReflectionHelper.java:94)`. So the NPE happened while getting the value of a member, which means the source object was null, as you correctly inferred. And below, `at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.DocumentBuilderIndexedEntity.buildDocumentFieldsForEmbeddedObjects` tells us this happened while processing an `@IndexedEmbedded`.